# Vim Colorscheme Not Loading

Tags: vimrc, vim8

I created an 8 colour theme, put it in .vim/colors & told .vimrc to use it but the default colorscheme loads instead....

Comment: I suppose we need more information to help you. What exactly have you done to create and use yor scheme?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, or at least a fix:

In the
~/.vim/colors/NAME-OF-COLORSCHEME.vim
file (not the ~/.vimrc file), put the `let g:colors_nane="NAME-OF-COLORSCHEME"`  **AFTER**  the `highlight clear` & `syntax reset` settings like this

```
highlight clear
if exists ("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif
let g:colors_name="NAME-OF-COLORSCHEME"
let colors_name="NAME-OF-COLORSCHEME"
```

I hope this helps others with the same issue.

PS I added both `let g:colors_name=` & `let colors_name=` to avoid issues if the global setting or the local setting is not applied properly.

Comment: This is covered in `:help color-schemes` via a link to `:edit $VIMRUNTIME/colors/README.txt`